# iTunes Connect Mobile Error 206

Tags: app-store-connect

I've searched a lot for this but I couldn't find the right answer.
I want to log in on the iTunes Connect Mobile app, but if I try to log in to the app, there comes an alert which says: 
"Authentication Error"
"No data found for your request (206)"

I really have to use the app, but this error blocks me. Is there a solution?
Is it a bug in iTC mobile or is my account the problem??

Comment: Same here. Only ITC on desktop works. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

It happened with me also, then realized Apple is doing a maintenance upgrade so no data is available to end users during that time.